# tmux key binding: Window not found

Tags: tmux, freebsd, key-binding

My problem is I can't make `tmux` key bindings to switch windows.

I'm running `tmux` terminal multiplexer on the FreeBSD server. `tmux` is started automatically for all remote logins using `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ $TERM = "xterm" ]; then
   ( (tmux has-session -t remote && tmux attach-session -t remote) \
  || (tmux new-session -s remote) ) && exit 0
   echo "tmux failed to start"
fi
```

By default, `tmux` windows are switched using <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> ...
I want to switch `tmux` windows using <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> ...

So I added the following lines to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -n F1 select-window -t :1
bind-key -n F2 select-window -t :2
bind-key -n F3 select-window -t :3
bind-key -n F4 select-window -t :4
bind-key -n F5 select-window -t :5
bind-key -n F6 select-window -t :6
bind-key -n F7 select-window -t :7
bind-key -n F8 select-window -t :8
bind-key -n F9 select-window -t :9
```

Now when I login and press F1, `tmux` says: "Window not found: :1".
I've tried to change to `bind-key -n F1 select-window -t remote:1`, the error message is similar: "Window not found: remote:1".

Switching windows from command line works, both `tmux select-window -t :1` and `tmux select-window -t remote:1`.

How can I make it work as a key binding?

Comment: The bindings look correct, and the bound command is obviously being run when you press F1. What does `tmux list-windows` show? Do you have `base-index` set to a high value (so that you do not normally have a window with an index as low as 1)?

Comment: `tmux list-windows` shows `1: bash* (1 panes) [108x48] [layout ce7d,108x48,0,0,0] @0 (active)`. `base-index` is set to 1 in `~/.tmux.conf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking for non-visible characters in your `~/.tmux.conf` file. I am able to reproduce your symptoms when the `bind-key` lines end with a CR (i.e. DOS/Windows-style line endings).

If you use Vim to edit, check the `fileformat` with `:set ff?`. If it is set to `dos`, then you can fix the file with this command:

```
:set ff=unix|w
```

If `fileformat` was already set to `unix`, then inspect the individual lines; if there are CR characters there, they should show up as `^M`.

Comment: Yep, I've had changed .tmux.conf in Windows and uploaded it via WinSCP Far plugin. I converted all line endings to Unix style per your recommendation, and tmux works as expected now. `tmux select-window -t :1<CR>` didn't work because there's no `:1<CR>` window, and error message about missing `:1<CR>` window didn't display `<CR>` part. So I can see true reason now, and thanks for your excellent answer.